# Cómo leer un archivo de excel con tildes en R

Tags: excel, r, utf-8

Tengo un archivo de excel que tiene tildes en algunos datos. El archivo tiene esta pinta:

```
ID  NOMBRE  SALIENTE
02201606000001ALCD                                                  ALIANZA DE CENTRO DEMOCRÁTICO                                                                                                                           OTROS
02201606000002AND                                                   PARTIDO SOMOS ANDALUCES POR ANDALUCÍA Y LOS PUEBLO                                                                                                      NACIONALISTAS
02201606000005BNG-NÓS                                               BNG-NÓS CANDIDATURA GALEGA                                                                                                                              NACIONALISTAS
02201606000007CCa-PNC                                               COALICIÓN CANARIA-PARTIDO NACIONALISTA CANARIO                                                                                                          CC
02201606000008CCD                                                   CIUDADANOS DE CENTRO DEMOCRÁTICO                                                                                                                        OTROS
02201606000009CCD-CI                                                CIUDADANOS DE CENTRO DEMOCRÁTICO-CANDIDATURA INDEP                                                                                                      OTROS
02201606000010CDC                                                   CONVERGÈNCIA DEMOCRÀTICA DE CATALUNYA                                                                                                                   CDC
02201606000011CENTRO MODERADO                                       LOS VERDES-ECOPACIFISTAS                                                                                                                                OTROS
02201606000012CILUS                                                 CIUDADANOS LIBRES UNIDOS                                                                                                                                OTROS
02201606000013C's                                                   CIUDADANOS-PARTIDO DE LA CIUDADANÍA                                                                                                                     CIUDADANOS
02201606000014C's                                                   CIUTADANS-PARTIDO DE LA CIUDADANÍA                                                                                                                      CIUDADANOS
```

Estoy intentando leerlo en R. Por ahora he intentado leerlo usando la funcion read.xlsx:

```
datos <- read.xlsx(file='nombres.xlsx', 1, header=TRUE, encoding="utf-8")
```

Pero cuando accedo al archivo, las tildes no se han cargado bien:

```
datos[3,1]
[1] 02201606000005BNG-NÃ“S
```

81 Levels: 02201606000001ALCD

También probé a cambiar el formato al archivo de excel y guardarlo como un csv utf8, pero me da un mensaje de error:

```
datos  <- read.table("nombres.csv", sep=";",header=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 11 did not have 3 elements
```

Por si influye en la consulta, trabajo con un ordenador con Windows10, el SO del ordenador está en español. Trabajo con Rstudio instalado en inglés, y he establecido que la codificación del fichero de código sea utf8.

EDIT: En respuesta a los comentarios, añado la salida del comando:

```
Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252"
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la información que te retorna esto: `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: Intenta cambiar el encoding luego de cargar el archivo, trata `EncodingI(datos) <- "latin1"` con eso se deberían ver bien.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que el `encoding` no es `utf-8` sino `UTF-8`, prueba con `read.xlsx(file='nombres.xlsx', 1, header=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: Usé el package `readxl` y usé el siguiente código: `df<-read_xlsx("D:/nombres.xlsx")` y cargaron las tildes que señala.

Answer (score 0):

El error que ocurre cuando ocupas

```
datos  <- read.table("nombres.csv", sep=";",header=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8") Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 11 did not have 3 elements
```

se debe a que detecta que una linea de tu .csv tiene una columna con datos diferente a 3, para evitar eso dentro de read.table agrega fill=TRUE  eso debería arreglar el problema si  es que una columna tiene menos de 3 datos, otra cosa que te recomiendo que realices es que agregues quote="" para evitar que tome la tilde como un separador.